# Query MongoDb based on Map Key Spring Repository

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

I need help to query nested documents. Using Spring Boot with MongoDB.

Structure:

```
public class Holiday {
  @Id
  private String id;

  private Integer year;

  private Map<String, List<HolidayElement>>  holidays = new HashMap<>();
}

public class HolidayElement {

  private String name;

  @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
  private Date date;

  private String note;
}
```

After saving everything the Json looks like:

```
[
   {
      "id": "5a153331b3cb1f0001e1edeb",
      "year": 2017,
      "holidays": {
         "BB": [
            {
                "name": "Neujahrstag",
                "date": "2017-01-01",
                "note": ""
            },
            ...
         ],
         "HH": [
             { ... }
         ]
    }
  ]
```

Now how can I get for instance: List of "HolidayElement" where the State is "BB"?

Comment: Why you use map for HolidayElements instead of List? Maps are hard to query. If you don't have a specific reason, I suggest to go with a List and put that BB, HH info HolidayeElement too, or wrap that info and HolidayElement into a new class and use List with this new class

Comment: how are you querying mongodb using MongoRepository or MongoTemplate?

Comment: I've got the following structure from the architect.. So if it's not possible I can talk to him..   @pvpkiran Using MongoRepository

Comment: Does **name** in HolidayElement means **State**?? Because there is nothing **State** in your Collection.

Comment: @MehrajMalik, yes it should have a short name of the federal states in Germany

Comment: If you were to do it in mongo directly, you can do it like, `db.getCollection('Holiday').find({'holidays.BB' : {$exists:true}})`, You cannot do this using repository, because you cannot write `@Query("{'holidays.?0' : {$exists:true}}")`. This will give you error, but you can do this using BasicDbObject and MongoTemplate. I think this is a better approach than getting all documents and then filtering in your code

Comment: @pvpkiran could you give me an example of how it would look like with mongotemplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a repository like HolidayRepository, you need to create a custom implementation since you want to use `MongoTemplate`. So your HolidayRepository will look like

```
@Repository
public interface HolidayRepository extends MongoRepository<Holiday, String>, HolidayRepositoryCustom {

}
```

And declare two new files HolidayRepositoryCustom and HolidayRepositoryImpl in the same directory(very important) as HolidayRepository

```
public interface HolidayRepositoryCustom {

  List<HolidayElement> findByMapId(final String mapId);
}
```

And the Impl class will look like this

```
public class HolidayRepositoryImpl implements  HolidayRepositoryCustom {


  private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

  @Autowired
  public HolidayRepositoryImpl(final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
    this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
  }

  @Override
  public List<HolidayElement> findByMapId(String mapId) {

    final QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilder.start();
    queryBuilder
        .and("holidays."+mapId).exists(true);

   final DBObject projection = new BasicDBObject();
   projection.put("holidays."+mapId, 1);

    String collectionName = "Holiday";//Change to your collection name
    try( final DBCursor dbCursor = mongoTemplate.getCollection(collectionName).find(queryBuilder.get(), projection)){
      if(dbCursor.hasNext()){
        DBObject next = dbCursor.next();
        Map<String, List<HolidayElement>> holidayElements = 
           (Map<String, List<HolidayElement>>) next.get("holidays");
        return holidayElements.get(mapId);
  }
    }
  return Lists.newArrayList();
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's awesome! Thanks a lot! But I need a list of HolidayElement.Is just change the type of the class and would work?

Comment: Ok, I'll try and let you know! Thanks

Comment: Thanks a loot!! I really appreciate it. Now it's working great.

Comment: Alles gute...... Can you change the subject of this question to "Query MongoDb based on Map Key Spring Repository". This will help if someone searches for this. Because  there are not many answers for this problem

Comment: Done! danke schön :) :)