# How to get parent object based upon key from child map in MongoRepository JAVA SpringBoot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

This is how my object looks.

```
@Document("parent")
public class Parent {
    @Id 
    private String id;
    private String field-1;
    private Map<String,Long> someMap;
}


{
    "_id" : "parent-id",
    "field-1" : "some value",
    "someMap" : {
        "category-5" : 123,
        "category-4" : 456
    }
}
```

I want to get this entire object when i search with **"category-5"** or **"category-4"**. I am using **MongoRepository** and **SpringBoot**.

I tried following approach but its not working for me

```
public interface ParentRepo extends MongoRepository<Parent, String> {

    @Query("{someMap :{$in: [?0]}}")
    List<Parent> findBySomeMap(String id);
}
```

or if anyone can help me to convert this into **MongoRepository/@Query** method that would be great and much appreciated
Goal here is to pass **CategoryId** as a parameter to query

```
db.getCollection('parentCollection').find({"someMap.category-4" : {$exists:true}})
```

**This method returns expected results**

Comment: Have you seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47438095/1606577)? Is it what you want to achieve?

Comment: yes it is related but it is getting list of elements inside someMap as a map.I want is Complete parent object based upon key inside some map inside that object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package com.somepackage.services;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.List;
import com.yourpackagestructure.Parent;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;

@Service
public class Service{

   private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

   public Service(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate){
    this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
   }

   public List<Parent> getParentList(String mapKey){
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("someMap." + mapKey).exists(true));
    List<Parent> parents = mongoTemplate.find(query,Parent.class);
   }
}
```